# vaadin: getting user logindata from external page

Tags: httprequest, vaadin, vaadin7

i wrote a normal html login form, that forwards to a vaadin project, where i want to receive the username and password and check if its valid. but i have problems getting this request.

when i add a requesthandler in the init() method of my UI class, i can only get the request data after the second call of the vaadin page (because at the first call of init, the hander ist not added yet)

```
 @Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    setContent(new MainComponent()); 
    VaadinSession.getCurrent().addRequestHandler(
            new RequestHandler() {
                @Override
                public boolean handleRequest(VaadinSession vaadinSession, VaadinRequest vaadinRequest, VaadinResponse vaadinResponse) throws IOException {
                    String username = vaadinRequest.getParameter("username");
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

so i tried to overwrite the VaadinServlet method doPost, but it does not get triggered. when i overwrite the methode service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response), this method is triggered a serval times for each request, so also not a good place to get just the userdata.

so whats the right way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont't know if this is the best solution, but at least it works. maybe this helps someone.

here a short explanation what i do. i retrieve the posted username and password from the post values of my plain html login formular from another url and see if it is existing in the database. if it exists, it returns the result, otherwise the value ERROR.

i extended the VaadinServlet and overwrote the method service like this

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    super.service(request, response);

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    if(username != null) { // called several times, only set when username is returned, otherwise the value remains "error"
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        this.result = getResult(username, Encrypter.encryp(password));
    }
}
```

and this is inside my class extended from UI

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {        
    MyServlet myServlet = (MyServlet) VaadinServlet.getCurrent();
    String result = myServlet.getResult();

    if(result .equals(MyServlet.ERROR)){ // check if the result set in the servlet is valid, otherwise forward to the loginpage
        goToLogin();
        myServlet.resetResult();
        return;
    }
    myServlet.resetResult();

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To whom it may concern - obtaining request and response in Vaadin 8 (which might be also available in Vaadin 7):

```
 VaadinServletRequest vsRequest = (VaadinServletRequest) VaadinService.getCurrentRequest ();
 HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = vsRequest.getHttpServletRequest ();

 VaadinServletResponse vsResponse = (VaadinServletResponse) VaadinService.getCurrentResponse ();
 HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = vsResponse.getHttpServletResponse ();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the request parameter directly through the `VaadinRequest` object that's passed into init():

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    setContent(new MainComponent()); 
    String username = vaadinRequest.getParameter("username");            
}
```

Comment: i tried that as well, but request.getParameter("username") always returns null.

Comment: Hmm, it worked in my simple HelloWorld example: http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld?username=test How are you transporting the parameter?

Comment: with a simple form <form method="post" action="/">
i receive lots of params, but except for "theme" they all start with v-. but neither the password, nor the username is included

Comment: ah, i see it works with "get" but not with "post". how can i get post params with vaadin.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. Then you'll need to implement some workaround. Maybe use OAuth or implement your login page with Vaadin if possible in your use case.

Comment: i did not try it with OAuth, but i already tried to put the loginpage inside vaadin, what lead me to another problem: there is no way to save the username for autocomplete, and the user has to enter the name each time again.

Comment: Since this is a HTML/browser related feature, this should also be possible with Vaadin. Never tried this before, though.

Comment: its seems that his feature only works with a static page, not with html generated by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It work for me perfect:
User is my simple class with username, name etc.

setting logged user in session:

```
public void setLoggedUser(User loggedUser) {
        this.loggedUser = loggedUser;
        getUI().getSession().getSession().setAttribute("loggedUser", loggedUser);
    }
```

reading user:

```
loggedUser = (User) getUI().getSession().getSession().getAttribute("loggedUser"); //return null if not logged in
```

Comment: where do you set the properties of this user object? how do you get the value for setPassword(String password)?

Comment: 1. User give you login and pass.
2 Find User with this login, check pass.
3 If login and password correct use setLoggedUser
4 then you can do witch User object what you want.
loggedUser.setPassword(String pass);

Comment: i can not login if i can not retrieve the username and the password from the post data of the other page, that's the essential problem. once i have the password and username everything is fine. anyway i already found a solution and marked this thread as answered.